# Spring boot app logs displays in debug terminal instead of regular terminal when started normally

Tags: java, spring-boot, visual-studio-code

This is very weird. When I start the spring boot app in visual studio code, the logs display in a debug terminal instead of a regular terminal (I don't know how this behavior changed because earlier the logs were displaying properly in the terminal). I am unable to find if there is settings that I need to change to fix this. However, when I run the spring boot app in a debug mode, the logs display as expected in debug terminal which is desirable.

Comment: Hi, can you add a screenshot please I do not really understand what you mean. Thx

Answer (score 7):

I found the reason why the logs for regular spring boot app start is showing up in debug console instead of terminal. VS Code has a launch.json file, which defines (console parameter) which defines where the logs should be displayed.

It was defined as

```
    "console": "internalConsole",
```

I changed it to

```
    "console": "integratedTerminal",
```

This fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Spring Boot Dashboard extension, it automatically creates a launch.json file.
You should change the json file for each project or remove this extension.
There are currently no settings for this extension.